# When Prompting for Biometric Permissions on iOS: Will I ever need to ask for TouchID to be enabled?

Tags: ios, permissions, settings, biometrics, touch-id

**Purpose:** I am working on implementing biometrics as a means of validation in app and I want to get the permission flow as minimally invasive as possible.

**Problem:** I know that FaceID requires an explicit permission and I understand that Apple made a UX decision to not prompt for TouchID in the same way, however does that mean that by default every application has the ability to utilize TouchID if the user has TouchID generally enabled (and has fingerprints enrolled)?

**Why Am I Asking:**
I know users may have a phone with TouchID or FaceID, with FaceID they give me explicit permission and that's updated in the application permissions. However, I'm confused if they will need to at some point need to go to their phone settings to allow for my application to use TouchID.

If that's the case, I want to prompt the user at First-Time Login to do this.